# ¿Se puede utilizar el subjuntivo después de conjunciones causales (puesto que, etc.) en frases negativas?

Tags: subjuntivo

Sé que para frases contrarias al hecho, debemos utilizar el subjuntivo.  Pero, lo utilizaríamos en un contexto similar al siguiente:

*María escribió sobre un tema diferente puesto que no le gustaba el tema del que habíamos hablado el lunes pasado. No quería que los demás se pusieran enojados así que les dijo que cambió de tema por el poco tiempo que tenía para entregar el proyecto. Raúl tenía dudas de esto de modo que* ***no cree que ella escribiera sobre otro tema porque (dado que/puesto que) no tuviera tiempo sino porque (puesto que/dado que) no le gustaba el tema.***

A mi modo de ver, "porque (dado que/puesto que) no tuviera tiempo" va en subjuntivo, de igual manera que "ella escribiera" porque toda esta situación es negada. Mientras puedo entender que un verbo en el modo subjuntivo sí puede seguir a "porque" ¿sería correcto que lo mismo pase después de "puesto que/ dado que?"  Se dice que normalmente sólo el indicativo sigue a esas conjunciones.  Pero, me pregunto si esto es una excepción.  Gracias por ayudarme.

Comment: No me parece que sea válido el reemplazo de 'porque' por 'puesto que' o 'dado que'. No todas las conjunciones causales se usan igual, por más que sean sinónimos.

Comment: Además, no me parece que *tenía dudas* y *cree* estén en concordancia, podría ser *tiene dudas/dudó* + *cree* , o sino escribí todo en pasado

Comment: Además, ahora que lo pienso ni siquiera sé de dónde sacaste eso de que 'sólo el indicativo sigue a estas conjunciones'. Facilita el trabajo que nos pasés todas las referencias de donde sacás información relevante como ésa.

Comment: Gracias por responder, tac.

El enlace siguiente es el que presenta "la regla" de las conjunciones causales:  https://spanish.kwiziq.com/revision/grammar/ya-que-puesto-que-porqueno-porque-followed-by-indicativesubjunctive-subordinate-causal-clauses

Acabo de aprender que un verbo en modo subjuntivo puede seguir "no porque."  Mis profesores nunca habían enseñado ese uso.  Aprendimos las conjunciones causales como un grupo sinónimo.  Entonces, yo intentaba aplicar este concepto a las otras conjunciones causales.  ¿Es correcto que un verbo en subjuntivo siga las otras conjunciones?

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con lo que dice el apunte. Ahorita te preparo la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

A ver, que haya conjunciones que sean sinónimas por tener el mismo significado no significa que el uso que se les dé sea el mismo, ni que sean reemplazables unas por otras en todos los casos. Incluso este mismo principio puede generalizarse para las palabras en general. No tengo una lista completa—y sería imposible hacerla—con todas las conjunciones y los usos en cada caso, pero leamos bien, y hagamos nuestra exégesis de lo que aparece en tu [página](https://spanish.kwiziq.com/revision/grammar/ya-que-puesto-que-porqueno-porque-followed-by-indicativesubjunctive-subordinate-causal-clauses):

- **porque** probablemente sea lo más versátil. Suele usarse sobre el final o al comienzo de la oración, en indicativo o en subjuntivo. Sin embargo, lo más común es **usarla al final, en cualquier modo**. Dudo que haya otra que sea compatible con el subjuntivo, al menos no lo es en cualquier caso.
- **dado que**, **debido a (que)**, **ya que**, **puesto que**, **en vista de que**, **habida cuenta de que**, etc., suelen usarse al comienzo y en modo indicativo. Pueden usarse al final, pero nunca en una cláusula subjuntiva.

Las formas correctas de reformular la última parte son:

En presente + presente

> Raúl **duda/estuvo dudando** de esto, de modo que no **cree** que ella **escriba** sobre otro tema **porque** no **tenga** tiempo sino **porque/debido a que/dado que/...** no le **gusta** el tema.

En presente + pasado

> Raúl **duda/estuvo dudando** de esto, de modo que no **cree** que ella **haya escrito** sobre otro tema **porque** no **tuviera** tiempo sino **porque/debido a que/dado que/...** no le **gustaba/gusta** el tema.

En pasado + pasado

> Raúl **tenía dudas** de esto de modo que no **creyó** que ella **escribiera** sobre otro tema **porque** no **tuviera** tiempo sino **porque/debido a que/dado que/...** no le **gustaba/gusta** el tema

Entre los primeros cuatro verbos, cada par debe concordar en tiempo. No mezclés tiempos porque, si bien puede ser más que aceptable hacerlo, en este caso los verbos no se van a llevar muy bien que digamos. Hay dos subordinadas más (comienzan a partir del primer porque), la primera es una negación en subjuntivo y sólo admite *porque*. La segunda es una afirmación en indicativo y por lo tanto admite cualquiera de las conjunciones presentadas. Quedaría por discutir si se permiten cosas como éstas:

> Raúl **duda/estuvo dudando** de esto, de modo que no **cree** que ella **escriba** sobre otro tema **porque/debido a que/dado que/...** no **tiene** tiempo sino **porque/debido a que/dado que/...** no le **gusta** el tema.

> Raúl **duda/estuvo dudando** de esto, de modo que no **cree** que ella **haya escrito** sobre otro tema **porque/debido a que/dado que/...** no **tenía** tiempo sino **porque/debido a que/dado que/...** no le **gustaba/gusta** el tema.

es decir, con las dos cláusulas finales en indicativo. Lo cual, a mi modo de ver, está perfecto ya que al haber demasiadas subordinadas anidadas podemos relajar la regla y sólo colocar la primera subordinada en modo subjuntivo.

Comment: tac, muchas gracias por toda la información. 

Veo que si se niega todo, hay que usar "porque + subjuntivo" solamente.   Si solamente se niega la primera parte entonces tengo las opciones de "porque, dado que etc. + indicativo."