# ¿Podemos reaccionar en el presente a una acción pasada?

Tags: concordancia-gramatical, concordancia-verbal

En [otra respuesta a una pregunta diferente](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/42284/se-puede-utilizar-el-subjuntivo-despu%C3%A9s-de-conjunciones-causales-puesto-que-e), un contribudor me corrigió una oración. Fue lo siguiente:

Yo puse: "Raúl no cree que ella escribiera sobre otro tema."
El contribudor me corrigió:  "Raúl no cree que ella haya escrito sobre otro tema."

Yo pensaba que tendríamos flexibilidad con los tiempos.  Es decir, hoy,Raúl puede creer o no algo que sucedió ayer.  En inglés, así podemos hablar: Raul doesn't believe that she wrote about another topic." Entiendo que oficialmente, deberíamos usar el presente perfecto indicativo o subjuntivo en tales situaciones. Creo que he visto que hay muchos nativos que coloquialmente dirían "escribiera" en vez de "haya escrito."  ¿No es así?

Comment: En la correción el tiempo del verbo creer no cambió....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te respondo por qué te señalé el error, aunque también desearía ver respuestas de otros para aportar más puntos de vista al respecto.

A muy grandes rasgos, distinguimos tres tipos de pasados: pretérito imperfecto, pretérito perfecto y pretérito pluscuamperfecto. El último de todos es el ‘pasado del pasado’ así que no interesa ahora. Entre los dos primeros, el imperfecto tiene como uso principal el de mencionar acciones pasadas que no finalizaron como se esperaba. En cambio, en el segundo la acción fue concluída tal como se esperó. Para simplificar, consideremos que los pretéritos perfectos simple y compuesto son equivalentes.

En el inglés la conjugación de pretérito mantiene la ambigüedad entre subjuntivo e indicativo, y entre pretéritos imperfecto y perfecto. Así, *wrote* podría ser *escribía/escribiera*, o bien *escribió/ha escrito/haya escrito*.

A diferencia de lo que se puede escuchar a través de ciertos mitos difundidos—de los cuales yo en su tiempo también me los creí, y aún cada tanto escucho algún profesor o compañero decirlo—**no es que piense que necesariamente esté mal ‘mezclar’ el presente con el pasado, PERO hay que saber cómo y cuándo es válido hacerlo**.

En este sentido, si el pretérito imperfecto expresa una acción no acabada regularmente, cuando el verbo esté en este tiempo mi pensamiento va a ser: *¿Y qué pasó entonces?* Para simplificar, cambiemos la frase a una afirmación y pensemos con ejemplos en modo indicativo:

> María escribió algo. Raúl **cree** que ella **escribió** porque le gustaba el tema. [OK, algún tiempo atrás escribió y ya dio por finalizada su acción]

> María escribió algo. *Raúl **cree** que ella **escribía** porque le gustaba el tema. [Escribía, ¿y qué pasó que ya no escribe?]

> Ella **escribía** pero le **pasó** [algo] y ya no escribe más. Raúl **cree** que ella **escribía** bien. [OK, escribía y sé qué pasó después que ya no escribe]

> María **escribió** [algo] y todo el mundo la felicitó. *Raúl también **cree** que ella **escribía** bien. [Escribía, ¿y qué pasó que ya no escribe? Si ’*escribió*’, ¿Por qué ahora me decís que ‘*escribía*’?]

> María **escribió** durante su juventud (hace mucho tiempo). Raúl cree que ella **lo hacía/escribía** muy bien. [OK, no sé que pasó pero, puesto que escribió hace mucho tiempo, espero también que ya no escriba más e infiero que hay algo que le tuvo que haber pasado—aunque no sepa qué.]

Es algo bastante común abusar del pretérito imperfecto en el lenguaje coloquial, pero, si la frase está muy fuera de contexto o se da a entender que la acción pasada fue finalizada normalmente, simplemente no queda bien combinar el presente con el pretérito imperfecto. Ahora, considerando que el subjuntivo es el que concuerda con las subordinadas en negaciones, y que en este caso las conjugaciones para el imperfecto y el perfecto serían respectivamente *escribiera(-ese)* y *haya escrito*; para cada ejemplo, negá la última frase y vas a entender lo que te quiero decir. **En general, los pretéritos perfectos e imperfectos no son intercambiables, ya sea en indicativo o en subjuntivo. Si la acción fue terminada con regularidad, entonces va el pretérito perfecto y no el imperfecto.** En tu caso, revisá la pregunta anterior que hiciste: efectivamente María escribió. No es algo que esté en duda. Raúl duda acerca de *por qué* escribió, por lo tanto los tiempos correctos son *escribió* y *haya escrito*.

Comment: tac, quiero que entiendas que no me quejo de nada.  En otro forum, hay reglas que dicen que tenemos que poner preguntas separadas. Por eso, puse la segunda pregunta separada.  Muchas gracias.

Comment: Falta: Rául creía etc. seguido de varios tiempos verbales.

Comment: @MarcosDiego nunca dije que estuviera mal lo que hiciste, al contrario, ponerlo como pregunta separada es lo que corresponde hacer. Sólo estoy respondiendo a tu pregunta, y de paso me gustaría ver más respuestas para comprobar si realmente es cierto lo que digo o es nada más que ‘un capricho mío’

Comment: @tac muchas gracias por la respuesta.  Y esa me conduce a otra pregunta.  No sé de los demás, pero yo trato de entender el concepto y no solamente una frase.  Pongo mi otra pregunta como una nueva.

Comment: @MarcosDiego Explicar todo el subjuntivo está complicado como para hacerlo en una respuesta a una pregunta. Además, hay varios libros y sitios que ya lo hacen. Básicamente es un tema de tiempo y de posibilidad o probabilidad. Por ejemplo, el imperfecto se prefiere en situaciones extremadamente difíciles de lograr e incluso puede usarse también para hablar del presente. Reitero que tu error consistió en haber usado el imperfecto para referirte a una acción que es evidente que ocurrió.

Comment: @tac te aseguro que no he encontrado un sitio que trate de esas matices. Claro que hay algunos que tienen mucha información. Lo que explicaste acerca de significados distintos para "porque, puesto que, dado que" etc. fue excelente. 

Me imagino que entiendes que no soy un estudiante principiante ni intermedio de español.  Así que no necesito aprender todo el subjuntivo sino esas matices intrincadas. Pero, muchísimas gracias por todo lo que has explicado.

Answer (score 0):

Muy buena explicación, tac. Yo también quiero ver las respuestas y perspectivas de otros a esta  pregunta.

Entonces, es verdad que hay esa flexibilidad. Te doy la razón en lo que dices en cuanto al papel del contexto.  Por eso, en mi otra pregunta, te di un contexto en vez de una frase sola.

Ahora bien, con respecto al primer ejemplo que pusiste:

*Raúl cree que ella escribió. [OK, algún tiempo atrás escribió y ya dio por finalizada su acción]*

Me imagino que se aplicará la regla con frases negadas que requieren el subjuntivo y el mismo contexto. Por ejemplo, será así:

*Raúl no cree que ella escribiera.*

Entonces, por extensión y aplicando la regla a otros tipos de oraciones que requieren el subjuntivo, creo que lo siguiente es correcto:  *Espero que ayer ellos entregaran su tarea. (I hope they turned in their homework.)*

Además, en cuanto a la concordancia de tiempos para el uso del subjuntivo, yo había racionalizado que lo que tengo abajo es correcto, especialmente si agrego ciertos detalles de contexto (utilizando el ejemplo con Raúl):

*Raúl no cree que ella escriba sobre ese tema.
Raúl no cree que ella haya escrito sobre ese tema la semana pasada.
Raúl no cree que ella escribiera sobre ese tema el mes pasado.
Raúl no cree que ella hubiera escrito sobre ese tema la primera vez que tuvimos esa tarea.*

Es decir que es la perspectiva del hablante y quizás del sujeto de la oración que influye en cuál de los tiempos del subjuntivo se usa. Raúl, en este momento, reacciona a una acción que tiene una cierta proximidad temporal cercano o lejano en el presente, el futuro o el pasado.

Quiero verficar esto para perfeccionarme y tener cada vez más dominio del hablado y escrito del español.   Gracias por su paciencia y sus respuestas.

Comment: Creo que te respondí algo que no estuvo del todo bien, y además me desvié hacia donde no me convenía. Te lo explico de otra forma. Volvé a la otra pregunta y leé el párrafo original. Empieza con  ‘María escribió’. Raúl no duda de que María escribió. Lo que está en duda es *por qué* escribió María. No está mal la negación ‘Raúl no cree que ella escribiera’, pero en ese caso se pone en duda que María escribiera, pero se sabe que efectivamente María escribió. Por lo tanto, lo que es correcto es *haya escrito*.

Comment: Lo segundo que dijiste tampoco es correcto, no se trata meramente de contar el tiempo físicamente, ni hay un límite físico (temporal) establecido que indique cuándo va un determinado tiempo verbal. Los pretéritos se usan en relación a otra acción sucedida que dé el marco de referencia. No se trata de simplemente ‘contar días’. El último ejemplo que di es un caso excepcional, pero reitero que en acciones finalizadas normalmente se usan los tiempos perfectos

Comment: Además ponés el pretérito imperfecto como si hiciera referencia a un tiempo anterior al pretérito perfecto, cuando no necesariamente ocurre así. Considerá que también podrían estar en el mismo tiempo ‘físico’